# android- How to run the program when i am getting error

Tags: android

Running the application in the Eclipse i am getting the following error.How to handle that.

[2011-06-29 10:35:46 - Roadbrake] Android requires .class compatibility set to 5.0. Please fix project properties.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this kind of error will ganrate when u use the android version which is support the JDK is not match in your computer

for that 
trace the path in eclipse :: project>>property>>java Compiler ..  set the JDK 1.6

Answer (score 2):

Under project properties (select project, then Alt+Enter).

Find Java Compiler, and change the Compiler compliance level:
[image: Project properties]